# Unable to download streamlit using pip in command prompt

Tags: python, windows, pip, command-prompt, streamlit

I'm trying to install streamlit in window10 using pip but I''m getting the following error after it says installing build dependencies:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c7t4bt44\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c7t4bt44\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running install
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  creating build
  creating build\src.win32-3.8
  creating build\src.win32-3.8\numpy
  creating build\src.win32-3.8\numpy\distutils
  building library "npymath" sources
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c7t4bt44\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c7t4bt44\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-grjth94n\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3avyqeva\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3avyqeva\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3avyqeva\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cython >= 0.29' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version<'"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"'' setuptools setuptools_scm wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

This is just a small part of the error which is very lengthy. What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version 3.8

Comment: I also had this problem when I was using python 3.8, the fix for me was to use python 3.7 instead. Try to create a virtualenv with python 3.7 and try again. Alternatively downgrading numpy worked for me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using windows, try to install or check if these two visual studio dist packages are installed:

- Visual C++ Build Tools installer: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe
- Go to this link and download the setup and install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Try to install the required python packages once again.

Otherwise as a hint, try creating a virtual environment and proceed with the installation there. Also I would probably check the python version. I had this issue when I tried working with python3.8 so maybe you can use 3.7 if you are using python3.8 now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is with your NumPy library.

How is your numpy installed? I would recommend using conda if you aren't already. Numpy sometimes has issues building on Windows.

I'll give you a link for conda installation and you could try if works this way.
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html

Comment: I will definetly not try using conda! why did you said that? can you explain